# What are the differences between array and linked implementations of the stack, list, and queue ADT

Tags: java, memory-management, stack, queue, abstract-data-type

First off I want to say these are three separate questions on a study guide of mine.

- "What are the differences between the array and linked
  implementations of the list ADT".
- "What are the differences between the array and linked
  implementations of the stack ADT".
- "What are the differences between the array and linked
  implementations of the queue ADT".

I thought that they all have the same differences which is based on the two memory allocation schemes I will explain below.

I know that arrays use an contiguous memory allocation where it is all in one contiguous block of memory. For the linked version it uses multiple non-contiguous memory blocks. I  understand the pros and cons to both contiguous and non-contiguous memory allocation so I am not looking for an explanation on that. I have been searching through both my notes and java book for more differences between them.

I am curious if there is more differences between an array and a linked implementation for stack, list, and queue ADT or if it is only based on the contiguous and non contiguous memory allocations.

Comment: Please use your favorite search tool and look for "difference between arraylist and linkedlist".  This question has been asked and answered thousands of times on the web.

Comment: @JimGarrison I have and read through chapters in my book. I havnt found any other answers thats why I am asking here. My question is if there are any other differences between the two depending on if they are implemented using a stack, list, or queue. So if there is more differences besides the CMA and non CMA or is that the only difference.

Comment: @Drizzy refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224888/java-are-1-d-arrays-always-contiguous-in-memory: Java arrays are not guaranteed to be contiguous in memory.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thank you for actually providing some information. That is interesting as my professor has not said this.