# what is index in linked List of java because linked list is not a contnious memory?

Tags: java

What is index in linked List of java because linked list is not a continuous memory ???

```
List l=new linkedList();
     l.get(index);
     l.add(index);
```

1. what is index in linkedList of java because linked list is not allocate continuous memory

Comment: Even `ArrayList` is not guaranteed to be backed by a single chunk of memory. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224888/java-are-1-d-arrays-always-contiguous-in-memory

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to `java.util.LinkedList`, the index is simply the position of an element in the `List`. Any `List` implementation is an ordered `Collection`, so elements can be accessed via their index.

However, for `LinkedList`, methods such as `get(index)` are not efficient, since they have to traverse the `List` from its beginning or from its end (depending on which is closer to the required index), which takes linear time.

Comment: thanks a lot Eran, One request to you.                                                       1.why we need to maintain insertion order of any collection (array list,linked list and all linked collection)                                                         2. Is there any benefit to maintain insertion order in real time

Comment: @sarvoday It all depends on the use case. Sometimes you need to maintain order (either insertion order or the order you get after sorting) and sometimes you don't. If you don't need to maintain order, and you don't want to allow duplicate elements, you can always use a Set instead of a List.