# Java - HashSet with char[] elements

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, char, hashset

I have a problem that I need help with. I have a `HashSet` that contains `char[]`. The problem is that I can't check if a value exists using the method `contains()`, it return false even if the value exists in the `HashSet`.

How can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744735/java-array-hashcode-implementation

Answer (score 8):

You can't use `char[]` in a `HashSet`, since the implementation of `hashCode()` and `equals` for a `char[]` is identity-based, not content-based -- in other words, if two `char[]` arrays have the same contents, that doesn't mean their hash codes are the same.  Use `String` instead.