# hashCode() called on array instance in Java

Tags: java, arrays, hashcode

I was just writing code, and suddenly I came across this warning in Netbeans:

> `hashCode()` called on array instance

It occurred in this piece of code:

```
public class SomeObject {

    private String a;
    private char[] b;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object anotherObject) {
        if (!(anotherObject instanceof SomeObject)) {
            return false;
        }
        SomeObject object = (SomeObject) anotherObject;
        return (this.a.equals(object.a) && arraysAreEqual(this.b, object.b));
    }

    // When I created the equals() method, Netbeans warned me:
    // 'Generate missing hashCode()'. Okay then, here it comes:

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (43 * this.a.hashCode() + 11 * this.b.hashCode()); // MARKED LINE.
    }
}
```

The warning occurs on the marked line. The IDE finds that I should avoid calling `hashCode()` on an array instance.

Now why should I avoid using `hashCode()` on an array?

Notice that I read [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java), but they didn't mention this.

Comment: If memory serves, arrays inherit the default `hashCode()` implementation, so perhaps that is why.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744735/java-array-hashcode-implementation

Comment: Riiight. That makes sense. Seems this question has its duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java arrays are directly derived from `java.lang.Object` and thus inherit the methods `equals` and `hashCode` from it.

The default `equals` method compares object identity (i.e. whether two references refer to the *same* object), and the default `hashCode` method will most probably return different values for different objects.

In most cases, this is a behavior that you do not want. You most probably want to compare arrays based on the *content*. Note, that your `equals` method seems to do that, which in turn means that your `hashCode` method is broken. Look at the [method's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) for the reason.

Java provides a class with helper methods for exactly that reason: [`java.util.Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html). It provides the methods `equals` and `hashCode` that are both based on the content of the array.

So you should write it like that:

```
public class SomeObject {

    private String a;
    private char[] b;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object anotherObject) {
        if (!(anotherObject instanceof SomeObject)) {
            return false;
        }
        SomeObject object = (SomeObject) anotherObject;
        return (this.a.equals(object.a) && Arrays.equals(this.b, object.b));
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (43 * this.a.hashCode() + 11 * Arrays.hashCode(this.b));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would better use:

```
java.utils.Arrays.hashCode(char[] a)
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_hashcode_char.htm

In your way you're not testing the contents of the char array.

> The java.util.Arrays.hashCode(char[]) method returns a hash code based
>   on the contents of the specified array. For any two char arrays a and
>   b such that Arrays.equals(a, b), it is also the case that
>   Arrays.hashCode(a) == Arrays.hashCode(b).

```
public void testHashCode() {

    char[] b = { 'a', 'b' };
    char[] a = { 'a', 'b' };
    System.out.println("HashCode b:" + b.hashCode() + " a:" + a.hashCode());
    System.out.println("Array hashCode a:" + java.util.Arrays.hashCode(a) + " b:" + java.util.Arrays.hashCode(b));
}
```

Result:

```
HashCode b:8995841 a:8995844
Array hashCode a:4066 b:4066
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Er, isn't `toString()` for arrays inherited from `Object`? So that would be basically as useless as plain `hashCode()`?

Comment: you're right. best option is first one. added a test

Comment: Perhaps you should suggest something more useful than `toString()` if you are going to include an alternative?

Comment: Completely agreee. I changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't override an `array` and it is using the default `hashCode()` implementation which can cause problems. You can consider this as a design oversight. You should either wrap your `array`s in an arbitrary object or don't use `hashCode()` altogether in the context of `array`s.

Answer (score 0):

The `hashCode` implementation for arrays is based on the identity of the array and not on the content. In most cases, this is not what you want, since two arrays with identical content will in general have different hash codes.

To base the hash code on the contents of the array you can use the `java.utils.Arrays.hashCode` method.