# Why Objects.hash() returns different values for the same input?

Tags: java, hashcode

I ran the follow script(java), and it gave me the weird result.
Does anyone can help to explain?

```
import java.util.Objects;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class CacheTester {

private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CacheTester.class);

    @Test
    public void hashCodeTest() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            // if I remove the third parameter, it works fine
            log.info(Objects.hash("getDemoCache", "1", new int[]{1, 2}));
        }
    }
}
```

Log Result(they are different from each other):

```
//...
2015-04-29 17:43:20 INFO  CacheTester:42 - 1431904540
2015-04-29 17:43:20 INFO  CacheTester:42 - 1859187447
2015-04-29 17:43:20 INFO  CacheTester:42 - -2146933580
2015-04-29 17:43:20 INFO  CacheTester:42 - -2074242201
2015-04-29 17:43:20 INFO  CacheTester:42 - 1363170000
2015-04-29 17:43:20 INFO  CacheTester:42 - 1040980265
2015-04-29 17:43:20 INFO  CacheTester:42 - 1639331053
2015-04-29 17:43:20 INFO  CacheTester:42 - 570765746
2015-04-29 17:43:20 INFO  CacheTester:42 - -2023288896
2015-04-29 17:43:20 INFO  CacheTester:42 - -1892732019
2015-04-29 17:43:20 INFO  CacheTester:42 - 1464306601
2015-04-29 17:43:20 INFO  CacheTester:42 - 921799986
2015-04-29 17:43:20 INFO  CacheTester:42 - 1037804977
//...
```

---- Background ----

I wanted to used my own keyGenrator for @Cacheable annotation(Spring & ehCache).

```
public Object generate(Object target, Method method, Object... params) {
    int key = Objects.hashCode(method.getName(), params);
    log.info("key = " + key);
    return key;
}
```

In this case, I find the cache are always missed.

Then I have to change to this:

```
public Object generate(Object target, Method method, Object... params) {
    int result = method.getName().hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + Objects.hashCode(params);
    return result;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: `int[].hashCode()` is identity-based, not content-based.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744735/java-array-hashcode-implementation

Comment: Thank you, all. Really learn a lot! =)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because `hashCode` for `int[]` is not overridden. There is no reason why two instances of `int[]` should have the same `hashCode`, even if the entries are the same.

Try this:

```
System.out.println(new int[] {1, 2}.hashCode());
System.out.println(new int[] {1, 2}.hashCode());
```

You will almost certainly see two different integers.

A good way to use `Objects.hash` with arrays is to pass `Arrays.hashCode(array)` instead of the actual array. In your case you could do:

```
Objects.hash("getDemoCache", "1", Arrays.hashCode(new int[]{1, 2}))
```

Comment: Thank you, @pbabcdefp, sooo much! You save my life.
Your explanation is very clear!

Comment: Aha! Thanks! I had a similar problem but I thought `Stream.mapToInt()` would've worked.  Apparently it returns an `IntStream`, so I needed call `stream.boxed().toArray()` in order to convert my integers into a list of objects. Only then I received consistent hash codes.