# LinkedHashMap<double[], Integer>, cannot access Integer with .get or .containsKey

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I have a series of small arrays (consisting of two doubles), many of which are
the same. E.g.

```
{5.0, 15.0}
{5.0, 15.0}
{5.0, 15.0}
{12.0, 8.0}
{10.0, 8.0}
{10.0, 8.0}
```

I want to be able to count the number of each arrays, i.e.

```
3 of {5.0, 15.0}
1 of {12.0, 8.0}
2 of {10.0, 8.0}
```

To do this, I tried making use of a LinkedHashMap (linked, because the order
might come into use later on):

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

public class MapArrayInt {
        Map<double[], Integer> arrays = new LinkedHashMap<double[], Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MapArrayInt mapArrayInt = new MapArrayInt();
        mapArrayInt.addArray(5.0, 15.0);
        mapArrayInt.addArray(5.0, 15.0);
        mapArrayInt.addArray(5.0, 15.0);
        mapArrayInt.addArray(12.0, 8.0);
        mapArrayInt.addArray(10.0, 8.0);
        mapArrayInt.addArray(10.0, 8.0);
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(mapArrayInt.arrays.get(new double[]{5.0, 15.0})));
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(mapArrayInt.arrays.get(new double[]{12.0, 8.0})));
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(mapArrayInt.arrays.get(new double[]{10.0, 8.0})));
    }

    void addArray(double val1, double val2) {
        double[] newArray = new double[]{val1, val2};
        if (!arrays.containsKey(newArray)) {
            arrays.put(newArray, 1);
        } else {
            arrays.put(newArray, arrays.get(newArray) + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

I expected this output,

```
3
1
2
```

but got,

```
null
null
null
```

I'm quite new to Java, but I suspect this might be because each `double[]` counts as a unique because they are different instances, even though they contain the same two doubles.

How can I fix this, if I should at all (is there a better way)? I just need a data structure that allows me to

1. Add `doubles[]`
2. Preserves order of `doubles[]`
3. Easily iterate through to get `doubles[]` and number of said `doubles[]`

Comment: You're right about why you have that problem, but can you explain what this is *for*? Doing stuff like equality comparisons (such as lookups) on floating-point is generally a Bad Idea.

Comment: Can you use `List<Double>` instead of `double[]`?

Comment: @chrylis A `map` represents an exercise; each `double[]` represents one set of each exercise, where `val1` is the number of reps, and `val2` is the value of the weight used. By retrieving the number of `double[]`s with the same values, I can easily print out something like `3x8 reps of 20kg`, where `3` is the number of doubles with values `8` and `20`.

Comment: Everytime you add something to the map, you're adding a **new** `double[]` array. When you try to receive a value from it via `arrays.get(new double[]{5.0, 15.0})`, you're also creating a **new** array, which is a different reference than those in your map. Hence, you get `null` when trying to retrieve an entry.

Comment: @shmosel I may be wrong, but I don't think a `List` would work with [my use case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44836067/linkedhashmapdouble-integer-cannot-access-integer-with-get-or-containske#comment76652843_44836067)

Comment: You could create a class that extends a `HashMap`. Otherwise, I would create a function that converts the `Double[]`s to `String`s and uses those in the `HashMap` instead.

Comment: The OP is using `double[]`. not `Double[]`, and converting to `String` is not an optimal approach. Neither is extending `HashMap`. Not sure why the OP went with `LinkedHashMap`. since insertion order doesn't seem relevant to the OP's situation. The problem, as others pointed out, is that arrays don't have value semantics for `equals`. It's also a Really Bad Idea to use mutable keys in a map.

Comment: @ning Technically, any use case requiring arrays can be substituted with lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I stated in my comment, with `new` you're creating a new instance of an object. Which means that the arrays you added with `mapArrayInt.addArray(5.0, 15.0);` and the arrays in `mapArrayInt.arrays.get(new double[]{5.0, 15.0})` reference **different** objects. That's why you get `null`, because for the map those are different keys.

In order to circumvent this, you could create a custom wrapper class

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Exercise {
    private final double[] array;
    public Exercise(double first, double second) {
        this.array = new double[]{first, second};
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(!(obj instanceof Exercise)) {
            return false;
        }
        Exercise other = (Exercise)obj;
        return Arrays.equals(this.array, other.array);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.hashCode(array);
    }
}
```

The `equals` and `hashCode` methods are important, when you want to use this class in collections like `Map`, otherwise the hashcode of `Object` is used for checking equality and you'd have the same problem as you have now.

Then, in your main class you can use it like so:

```
void addArray(double val1, double val2) {
    Exercise exercise = new Exercise(val1, val2);
    if (!arrays.containsKey(exercise)) {
        arrays.put(exercise, 1);
    } else {
        arrays.put(exercise, arrays.get(exercise) + 1);
    }
}
```

And `System.out.println(String.valueOf(mapArrayInt.arrays.get(new Exercise(5.0, 15.0))));`

Comment: I think this is the answer I am looking for. So using the static `hashCode` method on an array will return the same value for two different instances of an array with the same values/contents, so that `map.containsKey` works? Why doesn't this happen by default for normal `Array`s?

Comment: I just made almost the same Example below. Is it prefered to Override `equals` and `hashCode` rather than providing a single instance in such a case (my Example)?

Comment: Nevermind, I found an excellent answer about the hashCode stuff [on another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/744753/6910451)

Comment: If you're creating a separate class, dispense entirely with the array and use meaningful variable names.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:
I changed one of the doubles to int (you said you're representing reps and weight ... and reps can only be a natural number right?)

You could build create an Exercise-Class like below and use the static method "of" to create the instances:

```
package somepackage;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Exercise
{
    private static final Map<Integer, Map<Double, WeakReference<Exercise>>> instances = new HashMap<>();

    private final int reps;
    private final double weight;

    private Exercise(int reps, double weight)
    {
        this.reps = reps;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public static Exercise of(int reps, double weight)
    {
        if (!instances.containsKey(reps))
        {
            instances.put(reps, new HashMap<>());
        }

        Map<Double, WeakReference<Exercise>> innerMap = instances.get(reps);
        WeakReference<Exercise> weakRef = innerMap.get(weight);
        Exercise instance = null;

        if (weakRef != null)
        {
            instance = weakRef.get();
        }

        if (weakRef == null || instance == null || weakRef.isEnqueued())
        {
            instance = new Exercise(reps, weight);
            innerMap.put(weight, new WeakReference<>(instance));
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public int getReps()
    {
        return this.reps;
    }

    public double getWeight()
    {
        return this.weight;
    }
}
```

And then you could put those exercises in a map like below:

```
public void addArray(int reps, double weight)
{
    Exercise exercise = Exercise.of(reps, weight);
    if (!arrays.containsKey(exercise))
    {
        arrays.put(exercise, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        arrays.put(exercise, arrays.get(exercise) + 1);
    }
}
```

OR:
Instead of an `double[]` as key you can use the a `Map<Double, Integer>` as your value for 2 values:

```
package somepackage;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MapArrayInt
{
    private final Map<Double, Map<Double, Integer>> values;

    public MapArrayInt()
    {
        this.values = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void addArray(double val1, double val2)
    {
        if (!this.values.containsKey(val1))
        {
            this.values.put(val1, new HashMap<>());
        }

        Map<Double, Integer> innerValues = this.values.get(val1);
        if (innerValues.containsKey(val2))
        {
            innerValues.put(val2, innerValues.get(val2) + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            innerValues.put(val2, 1);
        }
    }

    public int getArrayValue(double val1, double val2)
    {
        Map<Double, Integer> innerValues = this.values.get(val1);
        if (innerValues == null)
        {
            // you may also throw an Exception here
            return 0;
        }

        Integer value = innerValues.get(val2);
        if (value == null)
        {
            // also here you may throw an Exception
            return 0;
        }

        return value;
    }

    public int getArrayValue(double[] values)
    {
        return getArrayValue(values[0], values[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nah, go with the wrapper class. It's a lot less complicated, and scalable to arbitrary-length arrays.