# Can Collection be used as an key in Hashmap java?

Tags: java, design-patterns, hashmap

I have following scenario (modified one than actual business purpose).

1. I have a program which predicts how much calories a person will
   loose for the next 13 weeks based on certain attributes.
2. I want to cache this result in the database so that i don't call the
   prediction again for the same combination.
3. I have class person 
   `class Person { int personId; String weekStartDate; }`
4. I have `HashMap<List<Person>, Integer>` - The key is 13 weeks data of a person and the value is the prediction
5. I will keep the hashvalue in the database for caching purpose

Is there a better way to handle above scenario? Any design pattern to support such scenarios

Comment: I have HashMap<List<Person>, Integer> - The key is 13 weeks data of a person and the value is the prediction ---> The person objects are not really data right? Since they only contain personIds and dates?

Comment: Also, it seems a bit counter-intuitive to me that a list of persons is the 13-week data for a single person. That's a good candidate for a class on its own.

Comment: Your data structure is incorrect.  The key appears to be a collection of different people.  In general, any mutable object should not be used as a key in a `HashMap` as any change to any contained value will break the map and prevent finding the object later.

Comment: As far as having `HashMap< List < Person>, Integer>`, Yes you can do that.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, 13 weeks is a dynamic one, it depends on input parameter. In another case it can predict for next 6 weeks

Comment: @i0707 that's not my point. My point is that when I see a class named `Person` I don't really think it means week.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, may be i should have modified the class like this Class Person {int personId, String weekStartDate, int hoursExcercised}

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842049/are-mutable-hashmap-keys-a-dangerous-practice

Answer (score 6):

Depends: the implementation of [hashCode()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/AbstractList.java#AbstractList.hashCode%28%29) uses the **elements** of your list. So adding elements later on **changes** the result of that operation:

```
public int hashCode() {
    int hashCode = 1;
    for (E e : this)
        hashCode = 31*hashCode + (e==null ? 0 : e.hashCode());
    return hashCode;
}
```

Maps aren't build for keys that can **change** their hash values! And of course, it doesn't really make sense to implement that method differently.

So: it *can* work when your lists are all **immutable**, meaning that neither the list nor any of its members is modified **after** the list was used as key. But there is a certain risk: if you forget about that *contract* later on, and these lists see modifications, then you will run into interesting issues.

Comment: the elements are fixed, that person object is meant only for key formation, we will override the hashcode and equals. Will still be a bad design?

Comment: @i0707 It should work, but the idea isn't very robust. If you ever *violate* this implicit contract (which is hard to enforce) you will run into all kind of weird errors.

Answer (score 1):

This works because the hashcode of the standard List implementations is computed with the hashcodes of the contents. You need to make sure, however, to also implement `hashCode` and `equals` in the Person class, otherwise you will get the same problem [this guy had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49424108/hashmap-key-generation-based-on-hashing). See also my answer on that question.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you define a class (say `Data`) and use it as a key in your hashmap. Override `equals/hashcode` accordingly with knowledge of data over weeks.